# Run video on boot system. [Ubuntu Server, raspberry pi 4]

Tags: mp4

Im trying to play video at system boot (ubuntu server) with :

```
vlc --loop filename.mp4
```

for the first time that video start everything is fine, but when restart it shows terminal for like 2 seconds and then video start.
I don't know if this is caused by performance of the architecture of raspi.

Anyone got this problem?